# Sql Insert Into Select statement PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to bind `$userId` value stored from `$_SESSION` inside an `insert select` statement but it seems is so wrong.

```
class Cart {

    public function addToCart($userId, $prodId) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `cart` (prod_id, user_id, prod_title, prod_img,quantity, price)
                SELECT product_id, //:user_id//, product_title, product_img, 1, product_price
                FROM  `products`
                WHERE  product_id = :product_id
        ";

        $q = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute([ 'user_id' => $userId , 'product_id' => $prodId]); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use named parameters you should use that name in the array you pass to the execute function (and also - not sure why you have the //...// (in the `//:user_id//`).

Check this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `cart` (prod_id, user_id, prod_title, prod_img,quantity, price)
            SELECT product_id, :user_id, product_title, product_img, 1, product_price
            FROM  `products`
            WHERE  product_id = :product_id
    ";

$q = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute([ ':user_id' => $userId , ':product_id' => $prodId]);
```

Comment: i just try to focus it in my description over the value needed to be binded

Comment: did you check the change in the `execute` in my answer?

Comment: anyway thnX for help

Comment: yup you add the :  for the named parameters but all the time i execute without it and works fine

Comment: thnX for help again